# How to Pass Vue data into Axios Post Request?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to pass some Vue data to axios.post Request but passing it using Vue template doesn't work. How would I go about passing the Data?

My Code:

```
<body>
    <div id="app" class="container">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" v-model="loginForm.username">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" v-model="loginForm.password">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" v-on:click.prevent="loginUser()">
        </div>

    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
            data: {
                loginForm: {
                    username: "",
                    password: ""
                },
            },
            methods: {
                loginUser() {
                    axios.post('/rest-auth/login/', {
                            // Using delimeters so [[ foo ]] but still doent work
                            username: [[ loginForm.username ]],
                            password: [[ loginForm.password ]],
                        })
                        .then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

FYI [[ loginForm.username ]] and [[ loginForm.password ]] renders fine in HTML (as text).

Comment: You don't have to use delimiters in javascript. Only use those in the template html syntax. What you have created now is username: Array[ Array['username comes here as a string'] ], in other words: Username is now an array of arrays with the first array index being the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comfusing delmitters in JS with  HTML.

To access data properties in vue, you have to do it as following:

```
this.loginForm.username
```

The `this` variable is the vue component instance. You can veryfi this by trying to console log `this` inside your function. `this` stores all things declared in your component. Computed properties, data properties, functions(methods) etc...

So in your case, you would sit the value of the key `username` like so:

```
{
  username: this.loginForm.username,
  password: this.loginForm.password
}
```